# Could not create content describer for com.example.cstfile. Content type has been disabled

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to add a content type for my XML files with a custom file extension(CST) and I get the following error -
**Could not create content describer for com.example.cstfile. Content type has been disabled.**

Here's my plugin.xml file -

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
      <content-type
            base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
            file-extensions="cst,xml"
            id="cstfile"
            name="CST File"
            priority="normal">
         <describer class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2"
                    plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime">
            <parameter name="elementNames" value="CSTFile"/>
         </describer>
      </content-type>
      <file-association 
            content-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
            file-extensions="cst">
      </file-association>
</extension>
```

I'm trying to figure out the reason by debugging org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog but have not found any reasons so far, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it comes from calls to `ContentTypes.invalidateDescriber` - the content describer has thrown an exception.

Looking at `XMLRootElementContentDescriber2` it will throw an exception if it gets a `javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException` exception when try to parse the XML.

There should be more information in the .log file in the .metadata directory of the workspace.

Comment: Yes I figured out the reason and it is because I had incorrectly specified the parameter name as elementNames instead of element, now I don't see the error anymore but my CST files are not validated for any syntax errors (missing tag, missing end tag etc..) like any XML files would be validated even though I have added the <file-association> attribute as per my plugin.xml file above, any idea on how to get my CST files validated by the Eclipse XML Validation framework?

Comment: Any hints on how to get my XML files validated by the Eclipse Validation Framework?